Closures in actors: Sending 'nonSendable' risks causing data races
Why is this not allowed in Swift 6 (Xcode 16 Beta 3)?
class NonSendable { }

actor MyActor {
    func foo() {
        let nonSendable = NonSendable()

        for _ in 1...3 {
            // ✅ Compiles fine
            bar(nonSendable)
        }
        
        (1...3).forEach { _ in
            // ❌ Sending 'nonSendable' risks causing data races
            // 'self'-isolated 'nonSendable' is captured by a actor-isolated
            // closure. actor-isolated uses in closure may race against later
            // nonisolated uses
            bar(nonSendable)
        }
    }
    
    func bar(_: NonSendable) { }
}


A very interesting case indeed.  If you add nonisolated to bar(_:), it stops complaining. So maybe the actor isolation of bar(_:) would somehow prevent the immediate execution of it (or rather the guarantee thereof) and possibly schedule it on self to be executed later? Just wildly guessing here. I'd be curious to learn the exact reasoning as well.

Swift 5.10 was overly conservative regarding passing non-Sendable types to different contexts. Specifically, we might create a non-Sendable instance, and pass it to some other context, but not use it outside of that new context. Swift 6 (specifically SE-0414) has improved this. As WWDC 2024 video What’s new in Swift says:

To ensure safety, complete concurrency checking in Swift 5.10 banned passing all non-Sendable values across actor isolation boundaries. Swift 6 can recognize that it is safe to pass non-Sendable values, in scenarios where they can no longer be referenced from their original isolation boundary.

So, as you noted, in Swift 6 (in Xcode 16 beta 3), you will get a warning with the following code:

In this case, though, it is the presence of the reference to nonSendable in the for-in loop that affects its isolation region. E.g., remove that reference and the error goes away:
actor MyActor {
    func foo() {
        let nonSendable = NonSendable()

        // for _ in 1...3 {
        //     bar(nonSendable)
        // }

        (1...3).forEach { _ in
            // ✅ Compiles fine
            bar(nonSendable)
        }
    }

    func bar(_ object: NonSendable) { }
}


This Swift 6 behavior is an improvement over Swift 5.10. See SE-0414 – Region based Isolation for a lengthy discussion regarding what improvements Swift 6 provides and the limitations that are still imposed.

For the sake of clarity, your original example (with both the for-in loop and the forEach closure) did not actually manifest a data race. But the question is whether the compiler can guarantee that the code is free from races: At this point it cannot.
In terms of work-arounds, either avoid attempting to use the nonSendable instance from two different regions, or make the object Sendable.

It's supposed to loosen overly strict rules but does the opposite in this case. When I change the Swift Language Version to 5 it compiles fine.
